# Create button group in React Native using react components

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am looking to see an example of button group something like in the example [here](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/button_group/).

ButtonGroup created using only React Native component like `TouchableOpacity` and `Text` etc...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Hope this is what you looking for

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const BtnGroup = () => {

    const [selection, setSelection] = useState(1);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.btnGroup}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.btn, selection === 1 ? { backgroundColor: "#6B7280" } : null]} onPress={() => setSelection(1)}>
                    <Text style={[styles.btnText, selection === 1 ? { color: "white" } : null]}>Button 1</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.btn, selection === 2 ? { backgroundColor: "#6B7280" } : null]} onPress={() => setSelection(2)}>
                    <Text style={[styles.btnText, selection === 2 ? { color: "white" } : null]}>Button 2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.btn, selection === 3 ? { backgroundColor: "#6B7280" } : null]} onPress={() => setSelection(3)}>
                    <Text style={[styles.btnText, selection === 3 ? { color: "white" } : null]}>Button 3</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.btn, selection === 4 ? { backgroundColor: "#6B7280" } : null]} onPress={() => setSelection(4)}>
                    <Text style={[styles.btnText, selection === 4 ? { color: "white" } : null]}>Button 4</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    btnGroup: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: "center",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#6B7280'
    },
    btn: {
        flex: 1,
        borderRightWidth: 0.25,
        borderLeftWidth: 0.25,
        borderColor: '#6B7280'
    },
    btnText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 16,
        fontSize: 14
    }
});

module.exports = BtnGroup;
```

It's nothing special just use useState and some dynamic styling rules.

Answer (score 0):

https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html

The above link has self explanatory examples with detailed usage.

I suggest to go through them first.

Answer (score -1):

You should go for a pre built set of component like react native paper which provide it for you.

Now, if you really don't want to (or can not), [here is a Snack Expo demo](https://snack.expo.io/SyMpPSise) (Not from me, found it on the web) showing something similar just with css, and here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class GridView extends Component {

   render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 1"/>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Button 2"/>
              </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

Here is what it looks like :

[image: Result of the code]

ButtonGroup are just multiple buttons aligned, so it should be enough to fill your needs. You can set custom css of your own to style it as you wish, this is just.. 2 buttons aligned.